# Developing Rest Service with Facebook Login or Google+ Sign In

Tags: rest, mobile

## Overview

- Basically I intend to develop a REST service for a mobile application.
- This REST service should only be accessible by authenticated users from mobile devices.
- I intend to use google+ sign in and Facebook login to manage the user authentication. That means my mobile app will have the access token from both.
- The REST will be off course running on HTTPS.

## Goal

1. I would like to validate if my implementation flow is correct
2. Find better ways for the design (using google sign+ in / Facebook).

## Implementation flow

1. User sign in their Google Account / Facebook in the mobile app.
2. Once the user received the token, the token will be sent to my server.
3. My server will validate the token with Google / Facebook and store that token in db DB (Assuming token validation goes well).
4. Mobile app will start sending REST request with the token appended to the HTTP header (Basic HTTP AUTH).
5. When my server request receive a request from the mobile application it will see if the token already in the database. If it is, it will serve the request, if not, it will return 401 HTTP error code.

I know this is quite rudimentary.

Please validate and suggest if there's a better way to achieve this (using google+ sign in / Facebook).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong about the flow.

But you will need to verify whether the Fb and Google+ access tokens expire or not. If they expire, then you might need to tweak the flow a bit.